# Principal Components in SAS

Tags: sas, pca, principal-components

I have written the following in SAS:

```
data test;
infile 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\test.dat';
input a b c d e id;
 run;

proc princomp cov out=a;
  var a b c d e;
  run;

proc corr;
  var prin1 prin2 prin3 a b c d e;
  run;
```

Is there a way to list the values of the principal components for each id? The output I receive are just summary statistics (i.e. max and min) and the correlations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listing values of Principal Components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053550/listing-values-of-principal-components)

Answer (score 1):

Try the OUTSTAT= option.

```
proc princomp data=out cov out=pca outstat=pcastat n=2;
run;
```

This will contain the Covariance, Eigenvalues, and Scoring Matrix.