# Listing values of Principal Components

Tags: pca, sas

I have written the following in SAS:

```
data test;
infile 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\test.dat';
input a b c d e id;
 run;

proc princomp cov out=a;
  var a b c d e;
  run;

proc corr;
  var prin1 prin2 prin3 a b c d e;
  run;
```

Is there a way to list the values of the principal components for each id? The output I receive are just summary statistics (i.e. max and min) and the correlations.

Comment: Hello, pcaguy, and welcome to the site!  I have to say, though, that your question, being about SAS, is more likely to get answered over on stackoverflow.  Of course some people here do know SAS, but programming questions in general are better served by stackoverflow than here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want separate analyses by ID then you can use a BY statement. This gives you separate principle components for each value of ID. The dataset has to be sorted by ID to use it in a BY statement.

```
proc sort data = test;
    by id;
run;

proc princomp data = test cov out = scores statout = stats;
    var a b c d e;
    by id;
run;
```

The output dataset which I called SCORES should contain all variables from TEST along with new variables which contain the principle component scores. The output dataset STATS contains various statistics including the eigenvectors.

A good place to look for SAS solutions is in the extensive SAS online documentation. The documentation for PROC PRINCOMP is [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/65328/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_princomp_overview.htm).

I hope that helps!